# How can I make this code repeat endlessly in the right way?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
x = input("What is your name? ")

if len(x) < 3:
  print("minimum 3 characters")
elif len(x) > 50:
  print("maximum 50 characters")
else:
  print("good")
```

So, when I try to use a while loop I do not manage to repeat the code the correct way, it just prints the answer endlessly and does not ask the question again, how can I do to restart the code properly using a while loop to repeat the entire process?

Comment: You need to include `x = input('What is your name? ')` in the while loop, it is evaluated only once and not every time you reference x.

Comment: Yes but when I do this, it doesn't entierly repat the process, it just asks me the question again and doesn't analyse my answer so it gives me the same one.

Comment: You also need to include the if-elif-else chain...

Comment: If I include the chain again, it will analyse my answer only once more, and then answer me the same thing  over and over without analysing anymore.

Comment: Wrap the whole thing in a while=True loop

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to use a `while True`.

```
while True:
    x = input("What is your name? ")

    if len(x) < 3:
        print("minimum 3 characters")
    elif len(x) > 50:
        print("maximum 50 characters")
    else:
        print("good")
```

Comment: You should add a ```break``` statement in the last line otherwise this will just loop forever